# "Force psuedo-tty allocation" doesn't translate to pssh

Tags: ssh, python-3.4, remote-access

Supposedly, pssh's -x option passes along extra SSH command-line arguments.  SSH's "-t" option should have taken care of the "Pseudo-terminal" error. Is there another pssh/ssh option that should be used?

```
# pssh -i -H ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 -H ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2 -x "-t -i /tmp/key.pem" 'sudo hostname'
[1] 13:46:54 [FAILURE] ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 Exited with error code 1
Stderr: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
[2] 13:46:54 [FAILURE] ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 Exited with error code 1
Stderr: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Without the "-t" and the "sudo", the command works fine, but I need to run some commands as sudo.

```
# pssh -i -H ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 -H ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2 -x "-i /tmp/key.pem" 'hostname'
[1] 14:08:35 [SUCCESS] ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1
ip-10-0-0-140
[2] 14:08:35 [SUCCESS] ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2
ip-10-0-0-139
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running pssh like this, so that the "-t" option is specified twice:

```
pssh -i -H ec2-user@... -x "-t -t -i /tmp/key.pem" 'sudo hostname'
                            ^^^^^
```

The [ssh man page](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh) says this about "-t" (emphasis added):

> -t
>   Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary
>   screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very
>   useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. **Multiple -t options
>   force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.**

You are apparently running pssh in such a way that ssh has no local tty. So you have to arrange for ssh to be run with "-t" specified twice. This forces ssh to request a remote tty, despite not having a local tty.

Comment: Although that did trick, a bizarre error is produced, but the error doesn't seem to affect the pssh execution.